# What is the current status of Kashida (in bidi) with luatex?

Tags: fonts, luatex, babel, bidi

I am trying to find out how to have Kashida justification in Luatex (in TexLive) for bidi text.

**Background:**

- I can see by searching that support might appear in `babel` [here](https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live-commits/2019-April/009423.html) but nothing implemented yet.
- In Xetex (`bidi` or `xeperisan` ?), Kashida justification is implemented by `\XetexInterCharToks`, using \hrule but not the glyph ( which was visually problematic in letter joints).
- Using (stretching) the Kashida glyph directly or applying the new variable fonts feature are the two alternatives.
- I also noticed that `\XetexInterCharToks` can be implemented in Luatex in someway [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21625/in-luatex-is-it-possible-to-change-font-language-according-to-the-script-glyphs).
- Previously, I asked about finding the width of glue space between chars [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356709/how-to-know-the-width-and-fill-the-glue-space-between-two-characters-when-using/356721?noredirect=1#comment878383_356721).
- No idea, if `harfbuzz` implementation (any support for Kashida ?) can be related. Harfbuzz can be used through `luahbtex` [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/493180/how-to-install-harftex-on-texlive)

**Edit (About Kashida):**

Kashida (from keshideh which means "stretched" in Persian) is a dash-like justification that can be added between (actually to the end of the first letter) some letters in Arabic/Persian/Urdu scripts (and probably Hebrew see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220255/kashida-like-hebrew-typesetting)). Its Unicode character is (U+0640), also known as Arabic Tatweel.

It has two functionalities:

1. aesthetically: more beautiful typesetting and a replacement for white-space justification
2. It can be used in stressing some words, as a replacement for capital letters or small-caps which do not exist in those scripts.

One can add manually the default character ((U+0640)) as many time as it seems appropriate:

```
کشیده
vs
کشیـــــــده
```

However, (1) any use of Kashida letter might create problem when searching for a word, and (2), the right amount of width of Keshida is not a proper multiple of the default width of it in a font. Therefore, a right solution might be to use variable fonts technology. This also can fix another problem that Kashida is not always a stretchable dash but it can be/should be a stretchable *curve* part of a glyph.

Comment: You can't implement `\XetexInterCharToks` in LuaTeX like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21625/in-luatex-is-it-possible-to-change-font-language-according-to-the-script-glyphs) anymore because the `token_filter` callback is gone.

Comment: in luatex rather than using interchar tokens and two runs to see the stretched glue you could probably do it in one pass by adjusting a glue node in the post linebreak callback

Comment: for harfbuzz you probably want to watch this issue https://github.com/harfbuzz/harfbuzz/issues/586

Comment: What is Kashida? I can guess from your question that it has something to do with spaces but the rules are unclear.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer stretchy line-y character thing that can stretch to avoid stretching space. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kashida

Comment: http://tug.org/tug2019/abstracts/anane-arabicmf.txt -- http://tug.org/tug2019/slides/slides-anane.pdf

Comment: @DavidCarlisle is this the callback you mentioned? http://wiki.luatex.org/index.php/Post_linebreak_filter

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have looked at those issues, but could not figure out if in Luatex environment this is the responsibility of Luatex or Harfbuzz to decide about using Kashida. I put a reference there to this discussion anyway.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I added an edit to explain more.

Comment: @Shahryar yes that one

Comment: @HenriMenke, thanks for the link. But I am not sure if the "Visual METAFONT" can help in our case (if I could understand the slides correctly). The length of a kashida depends on the paragraph parameters and not just the series of letter. So, applying kashida should be something in luatex or harfbuzz but not the font internal.

Comment: Improving searching should be possible, one could try to add an empty /ActualText in the pdf the luaotfload code does this already for a number of glyphs (but I would have expected the pdf reader to know that it should ignore the glyph).

Comment: @Thanks for mentioning /ActualText. It can probably solve the problem. Besides pdf readers, it is search engines which should find words correctly (which I guess /ActualText would fix it at the same time).

Comment: Indeed, I've studied the possibility of adding some support for kashida in `babel`, but my first experiments were quite unsatisfactory (in particular, the `\hrule` hack), and I haven't investigated any further.

Comment: @JavierBezos, yes `\hrule` hack creates unsatisfactory results (I remember that once I have tried to stretch the kashida glyph itself, but do not remember if it created different result, probably not).
Any plan for further investigation in future?

Comment: @Shahryar Very likely, if nobody tries before :-).

Comment: Once variable fonts are supported, there’s a SIL-licensed font which looks suitable for experimenting with kashida: https://github.com/aminabedi68/Estedad

Comment: @Shahryar Well, I've finally decided to tackle the task and there wiil be  very likely at least some basic support in `luatex` very soon. I have my doubts that with `xetex` we can go much further than, eg, `texnegar`. See an example here: https://twitter.com/javier_bezos/status/1387742677731524609 .

Comment: @JavierBezos, that is a good news. Since 2019, variable fonts became more common, most of them with support for Kashida. Such as:

https://github.com/rastikerdar/vazir-font

https://fontiran.com/%d9%81%d9%88%d9%86%d8%aa-%d8%af%d8%a7%d9%86%d8%a7-%d8%ad%d8%b1%d9%81%d9%87%e2%80%8c%d8%a7%db%8c/

However, I could not see Tex implementations based on that. Solutions such as TexNegar do not utilize this feature but rely some older work-around which is limited to specific fonts, with serious problems.

Similarly, I think Luatex is the one to invest in.

Comment: @Shahryar I'll take a look at the font (thank you for the pointer!). At the moment, I am focusing on the `jalt` alternatives and the insertion of kashida.

Comment: @JavierBezos Good!

I provided two links, one seems missing in the above:

https://fontiran.com/%d9%81%d9%88%d9%86%d8%aa-%d8%af%d8%a7%d9%86%d8%a7-%d8%ad%d8%b1%d9%81%d9%87%e2%80%8c%d8%a7%db%8c/

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`TeXNegar`](https://ctan.org/pkg/texnegar) package.

From the User Documentation of the package:

The TEXNegar package implements kashida justification in LuaTeX and XeTeX and fixes known bugs in xepersian.